# android Get email suggestions in auto complete textview

Tags: android, email, autocompletetextview

i want to get email in my contacts as suggestions using auto complete textview. 
i am currently getting contact's name , contact's id and number like

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void PopulatePeopleList() {

        mPeopleList.clear();

        try {

            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                String num = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                num = num.replaceAll(" ", "");
                String name = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String id = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();

                NamePhoneType.put("Name", name);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", num);
                NamePhoneType.put("Type", id);
                mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);

                // Add ArrayList names to adapter

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AutocompleteContacts", "Exception : " + e);
        }

        // startManagingCursor(people);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up your AutoCompleteTextView? You just need to put this data into the adapter.

Comment: this data is accessible in autocompleteTextview , but i want to get email address in autocompleteTextView, emails which are in my contacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while, though for those who seek a solution for the same issue, I wrote [EmailCompletionEditText](https://ranyalbegwein.silvrback.com/email-completion-edit-text) which can give you a complete answer or an idea for writing a solution yourself.

In case of a broken link, I'm attaching the source code here:

```
/**
 * Created by Rany Albeg Wein on 24/01/2016.
 */
public class EmailCompletionEditText extends MultiAutoCompleteTextView {
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;

    public EmailCompletionEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public EmailCompletionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public EmailCompletionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public EmailCompletionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                                   int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        final String[] from = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                                           ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO_URI};

        final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tv_contact_name,
                                   R.id.tv_contact_email,
                                   R.id.iv_contact_photo};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.contact_row, null, from, to, 0) {
            @Override
            public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {

                final int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
                return cursor.getString(emailIndex);
            }
        };

        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                String query = constraint.toString();

                final String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " LIKE ? "
                        + " OR "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
                        + " LIKE ? ";

                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + query + "%"
                        , "%" + query + "%"};

                return mContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

            }
        });

        setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14458106)

Comment: Edited accordingly. Thank you !